# Postgresql query COUNT and MAX together?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT id,icon,type,cnt 
FROM  capability 
JOIN (
    SELECT s0_.capability_id AS capability_id0 ,
           count(capability_id) as cnt  
    FROM service_offer_capability s0_ 
    INNER JOIN service_offer s1_ ON s0_.service_offer_id = s1_.id 
    WHERE s0_.value <> 'i:0;' AND s1_.service_id = 2 
    GROUP BY s0_.capability_id
) af
ON af.capability_id0=id;
```

All i want to do is to have a max(cnt) as an extra column. I know that you can order by cnt and get the first but i am looking for an alternative..Is it possible or i have to run multiple queries?

Comment: You can certainly do it in one select statement (although it'd more or less double your code and almost certainly NOT be DRY without using a view or something) I'm just wondering why.

Comment: @JayC what do you reccomend ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT id,
       icon,
       type,
       cnt,
       max(cnt) over () as max_cnt
FROM  capability 
JOIN (
    SELECT s0_.capability_id AS capability_id0 ,
           count(capability_id) as cnt  
    FROM service_offer_capability s0_ 
    INNER JOIN service_offer s1_ ON s0_.service_offer_id = s1_.id 
    WHERE s0_.value <> 'i:0;' AND s1_.service_id = 2 
    GROUP BY s0_.capability_id
) af
ON af.capability_id0=id;
```

Comment: @JayC: You may want to use `LEFT JOIN` so you don't lose rows from capabilities without a match in the subquery.